# What regulations should a European driver know when driving in the US?

Tags: usa, europe, driving, legal, regulations

There are the obvious ones. The US has the keep-your-lane system, where as in Europe you are expected to keep to the right (left for UK) as long as possible. 
On my latest travel to the US, I was confronted with the possibility to go through a red light if you turn right, unless it is explicitly not allowed.

**What should a european driver know when driving in the US?** What are the do's and don'ts compared to driving in Europe.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Great comment, you should turn it into an answer so I could give your credits. You often hear people saying that they wish that Europe would adapt the keep-your-lane system from the US. Funny that there is no such thing. What sign indicates a keep-your-lane road? Is passing on the right then also as forbidden as it is overhere?

Comment: `The US has the keep-your-lane system` I don't think this is true... and I know it's now *not* true in Kansas. You can now be ticketed for staying in the left lane.

Comment: The "keep your lane" concept is unknown everywhere on the North American west coast:  BC, Washington, Oregon, California, Idaho, Nevada, etc.

Comment: @wallyk: I have to disagree about California. I never knew the concept to have a *name*, but certainly the practice is to find a lane and stick to it - there is explicitly no need to go back to the right lane(s) once you're done passing. This is different than many left coast and flyover states, where they all inexplicably like to make half of the road mostly-useless (which is what they become if the left lane is only to be used for passing).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The other two answers pretty well covered things, but here are a few more notes:

- [In some states, it is legal to make a left turn through a red light if both intersecting streets are one way.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_turn_on_red#Left_turn_on_red)  (In other words, one can treat the red light as a stop sign.)
- In some (maybe all?) states, one can be ticketed for driving too slow, even if there is no posted minimum speed limit. (The citation is usually for something like, "Impeding the flow of traffic.")
- In most states, it is illegal to be seen drinking alcohol in public, including (and especially) as a passenger in a car.  However, [there are some states in which it is legal for car passengers to drink alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_open_container_laws#Open_containers_in_vehicles).  In Mississippi, it is still legal for drivers to consume alcohol while driving, as long as their blood alcohol content is below 0.08%.
- From personal experience, I've noticed that in some European countries it is common for cars that are about to overtake on a highway to hover for a while between two lanes (I saw this a lot in Iberia).  Also, in Scandanavia in particular, I saw a lot of cars in the right lane actually move onto the shoulder while being overtaken.  In my experience, I have never seen either of these practices in the US, and they likely violate many states' regulations.
- Given the automotive boom of the mid-20<sup>th</sup> century, many large, multi-lane roads were built.  As such, putting traffic lights at the intersections of these 3+ lane roads to allow left turns became a bottleneck.  Therefore, some states implemented other means of turning left on large roads.  For example, the [jughandle turn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jughandle) is very common, especially in the Northeast.  The "[Median U-Turn Crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_left)" is also very common in Michigan.
- This last note isn't so much about regulations, but I'd highly recommend bringing or renting a GPS/SatNav. Unlike in most of Europe, I find signage in the US to be particularly bad. For example, in Europe there are often signs in the countryside pointing one to the direction for the nearest cities. In the US, such signs usually only point to the closest highway, so unless you know specifically which highway will point you to your destination, you may be out of luck.

**Additions** (2011-07-19):

- In an increasing number of states, it is illegal to operate a mobile phone while driving.  The wording of the laws varies by state; in some it is even illegal to touch a mobile phone while driving.  In most (if not all) states it is okay to use a hands-free device (*e.g.*, a bluetooth headset), though.
- In some states (*e.g.*, Oregon and New Jersey) it is illegal to pump your own fuel; *all* of the gas stations are "full service" (*i.e.*, an attendant must pump the fuel for you).  In these states it is not necessary for you to tip the attendant for his or her service, although I am sure it is appreciated.  I am not sure about Oregon, but at least in New Jersey I know that it is illegal to exit your vehicle while your fuel is being pumped (presumably for the safety of the attendant).  I believe these laws were enacted in the late 1940s/early 1950s because the government thought that pumping fuel was too difficult and hazardous an activity for the average motorist.  The laws have probably persisted because repealing them would mean the loss of a great number of gas attendant jobs. In Oregon, it is possible to find yourself stranded after hours in the middle of nowhere until the gas station opens, so plan ahead.
- If you plan on using a radar detector, [the laws vary by state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_detector) (much in the same way that they vary by country in Europe).  In general, it is legal to use a radar detector in all states *except* Virginia and Washington, D.C.  In some states (*e.g.*, Minnesota and California), it is illegal to mount the radar detector from the windshield, since it obstructs the driver's vision.

Comment: Your first and last addition are not a points of difference. The same could be said for Europe. Nice point on gas stations.

Comment: @Andra: I know, I just wanted to emphasize the fact that there are not country-wide regulations on those practices; the laws vary state-by-state.  Good point though.

Comment: Moving over to the shoulder to allow a car to pass is a common custom in Texas and presumably many other southern states in the USA, but only on two lane roads. A "Thank you" wave is generally in order if you are the person overtaking the other car in they move over for you.

Comment: I disagree about the GPS, but for the same reason. I never had big issues driving in the US because if I was on a long trip, I'd plan the itinerary. While in France, for local traffic, you should follow signs to the next big city sometimes 50 km away, even if you drive a couple km.

Comment: In Texas, it is (or at least was) a requirement that a vehicle being overtaken by a passing vehicle must pull over to the right. I've never seen that anywhere else in the US, though.

Comment: @JohnFx I thought most states had laws against driving on the shoulder; is that not the case in TX?

Comment: There are a number of exceptions in the Texas traffic code including " to allow another vehicle traveling faster to pass;"

Comment: While Oregon bans self-service fueling, there are some native American reservations which permit it, which means only 99.99% of Oregon gas stations are not self serve.  In 600,000+ miles over 40 years, I have never been stranded waiting for a gas station to open.  It just means it might be necessary to drive further than expected to get to an open station.  Along the Interstates, virtually all stations are open 24 hours, especially on holidays.  One is free to get out of the vehicle at fuel stops, like to wash the windows or peruse the convenience store.

Answer (score 19):

To me, these are the two most important things drivers visiting the US should know:

1. **Different states have different laws**. Knowing what the law is in California doesn't help if you get pulled over in one of the other 49 states.
2. **Get your information from a trusted source**. There's a lot of misinformation out there; the only way to know what the law really says is to get it directly from the state.

   For instance, here's what [California's official Driver Handbook](http://dmv.ca.gov/pubs/hdbk/driver_handbook_toc.htm) says about [intersections](http://dmv.ca.gov/pubs/hdbk/right_of_way.htm#intersections) (below emphasis mine):

   > - **At intersections without "STOP" or "YIELD" signs, slow down** and be ready to stop. Yield to traffic and pedestrians already in the intersection or just entering the intersection. Also, **yield to the vehicle or bicycle which arrives first, or to the vehicle or bicycle on your right** if it reaches the intersection at the same time as you.
   > - At "T" intersections without "STOP" or "YIELD" signs, yield to traffic and pedestrians on the through road. They have the right-of-way.
   > - When you turn left, give the right-of-way to all vehicles approaching that are close enough to be dangerous. Also, look for motorcyclists, bicyclists, and pedestrians. When you turn right, be sure to check for pedestrians crossing the street and bicyclists coming up behind you on the right. On divided, highways or highways with several lanes, watch for vehicles coming in any lane you cross. Turn either left or right only when it is safe.
   > - **When there are "STOP" signs at all corners, stop first** then follow the above rules.
   > - If you have parked off the road or are leaving a parking lot, etc., yield to traffic before reentering the road.

Comment: same in Europe, different countries have different laws (and they may well contradict each other or even themselves).

Comment: As far as I know, the 4-way stop sign is a North American speciality. These generally function as FIFO queues, but not always. For example, if a pedestrian is blocking the car that arrived first, it will have to wait, and cars parallel to that pedestrian will go.

Answer (score 17):

This isn't a regulation, but it could be very important nonetheless. If stopped by the police, do not have the reflex of reaching into the glove box for the car's papers. This could be interpreted as reaching for a gun, and you risk getting shot preemptively. Once you've stopped your car, remain in your seat, and **keep your hands well in evidence** (on the steering wheel).

See also [more recommendations by a US police officer](http://business.wikinut.com/21-Things-Not-to-Do-When-The-Police-Stop-You/1_.fa4yt/).

Comment: "Do not keep driving". This is a worrying advise since some people dress up as police officers driving in a police car lookalike to rob you. In some countries the advise is to keep driving until you are in a place with enough witnesses. I can imagine this advise to be also valid in a widespread country like the USA, with many deserted places.

Comment: In some countries the real police will rob you. This has happened to two groups of friends of mine in Mexico City.

Comment: @hippietrail This happens in the US, as well, although it usually takes the form of the officer offering to let the driver "avoid points and court fees" (traffic citations include additional fees for court costs, even if you decline a court hearing) by paying cash (which then goes into the officer's pockets). Not sure how likely they would be to try this on a driver visiting from another country, though.

Comment: @Beofett: When I was driving in the US as a 21-year-old white visitor from a non-poor country the police were usually extra nice to me and let me get away with a lot.

Comment: @hippietrail good to hear! We have a lot of really wonderful law enforcement personnel in the US, but unfortunately it only takes one bad one to give a really bad impression.

Comment: @hippietrail. Good on you for being aware of your privilege. Your experience with US law enforcement won't necessarily predict how they'd treat other people.

Comment: FYI: It is a REALLY bad idea to try to bribe a police officer in the USA. You are more likely to get in further trouble than get out of it.

Comment: @Andra: As a US resident (but not a police officer) I would definitely stop driving if you get pulled over.  I have heard that if you are worried that the car pulling you over is not a real police officer, pull over and when the officer comes to the car, roll down the window and tell them your concern and ask them to call another police car. If you continuing to drive the real police will interpret as you fleeing, presumably because you have an outstanding arrest warrant or something you will be in much more trouble).  Personally, I have never, ever worried about this while driving in the US.

Comment: Also good to know: in the US, the police car that is pulling you over will stop behind you, not in front of you.  Fines are never issued on the spot, the police officer never handles money, and any suggestion of payment will likely be construed as attempted bribery.

Comment: Like many other traffic laws, payment for speeding tickets also varies by state.  For example, at least up until a few years ago, [it was legal to pay the officer in cash for minor speeding offenses in Montana](http://www.nytimes.com/1989/07/10/us/speeding-is-easy-and-almost-free-in-montana.html).  The officer would even follow you to a nearby ATM if you needed cash.  A friend of mine who used to live in Montana also confirmed this.  I am not sure if it is still the case, though.

Comment: @auujay At least once when there was a specific problem with fake cops pulling people over I've seen local police (western PA area) on TV recommend slowing down and turning on your 4-way flashers to acknowledge that the cop wants you to pull over but to keep driving (what you should do if the current location isn't safe to pull over) until you can pull into a store/gas station parking lot with witnesses/security cameras.

Answer (score 13):

The following apply to [California](http://www.dmv.ca.gov/pubs/hdbk/driver_handbook_toc.htm) versus [Sweden](http://www.transportstyrelsen.se/sv/Vag/Trafikregler/), at least:

- In California, at uncontrolled intersections (without traffic signs or signals) you yield in theory "to the vehicle or bicycle on your right if it reaches the intersection at the same time as you" (**Priority to the right**). In practice, though, most intersections are controlled by stop signs or traffic lights, with uncontrolled intersections only in very undeveloped areas with little traffic, making this mostly a non-issue. In Sweden, the same "Priority to the right" [*högerregeln*] system applies, but the big difference is that many intersections are not controlled, and there are additional signs (priority road, end of priority road, intersection shape and priority) and rules (*utfartsregeln*, *svängningsregeln*, etc) to negate the priority to the right or otherwise modify the right of way, making it critical to understand and keep in mind "Priority to the right" all the time.
- In California, you're advised to "drive in the lane with the smoothest flow of traffic", though in general you're expected to **keep to the right** (if two lanes) or choose the middle lane (if three lanes). In Sweden, that's true but there's an important exception: if there are two lanes in the same direction and the speed limit is 70 km/h or lower, you are free to drive in any lane and may even pass to the right.
- In California, there is no guideline for **when another driver is passing you**. In Sweden, if another driver is trying to pass you, even if the pass is wrong or dangerous, you are obligated to facilitate the pass by moving to the right. You may specifically even drive on the shoulder if it is reasonable.
- In California, **when entering a freeway**, "freeway traffic has the right-of-way". In Sweden, if a specific on-ramp exists, neither side has right-of-way. Both sides are obligated to show mutual consideration when merging.
- In California, you must wear **seat belts** at all times. In Sweden, seat belts are specifically not required when backing the vehicle or when driving in a parking lot, gas station, etc.
- In California, you may **turn right on red** ("you may turn right if there is no sign to prohibit the turn"). In Sweden, there is no such provision, though there is an obscure case where this is possible. If there is a "Stopp vid signal" sign [Stop for the signal] and the traffic light is located after the intersection, the light only applies to you if you are crossing the intersection. If you're turning right, the light does not apply and you may effectively turn right on red. (This is not common.)

Comment: Seriously? One may pass on the right in Sweden? I live in Sweden, my girlfriend is taking her exam in Sweden, but I've never heard this (OK, I do live 650 km from the nearest highway).

Comment: Yes, Google for "omkörning på höger sida". One of the specific exceptions on http://korkortonline.se/teori/omkorningar/ for example, says "*Tillåtet om hastighetsbegränsningen är max 70 km/h och det finns minst 2 markerade körfält i samma riktning*. [Allowed if the speed limit is max 70 km/h and there is at least two marked lanes in the same direction.]

Answer (score 7):

In most of (mainland) Europe there's a priority for traffic coming from the right (on an intersection without traffic lights), and you don't necessarily have to stop when you see there's no other traffic.

So one of the things I think a lot of Europeans will have trouble with at first when driving in America is the fact that on an intersection without traffic lights, there's a system of first come first serve, <strike>and you ALWAYS HAVE TO STOP</strike> (apparently - see the comments - you only have to stop when there is a stop sign). There are a lot of intersections in America which have a stop sign on all four directions, then the first come, first serve system is applied. That's something which doesn't exist in Europe because you simply don't have intersections with stop signs in all directions (mostly only 2 of them and the main road has priority). At least I don't know of any.

I say at first, because I think it's a very good (if not better) system *once you get used to it*. But that might also have something to do with the fact that most intersections in America are much larger than they are in Europe, so it's usually much easier to see all the traffic coming from the different directions.

Comment: Are you sure about your second paragraph?  In Canada you don't have to stop at an intersection unless you have either a stop light or a stop sign, and I haven't observed anything different in my trips to the US or when I lived in Chicago.  [Wikipedia seems to agree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic#Intersections); it says both Europe and the US prioritize traffic from the right at uncontrolled intersections, but mentions nothing about stopping by default.  [Same as Canada](http://www.drivingschool.ca/drivereducation/page3.html).

Comment: Matthew Read is correct. In the US, you only have to stop at an intersection without a traffic light if there is a stop sign (this is the explicit purpose of our stop signs).  Many intersections will have stop signs present only for some branches, and not all (i.e. a 4-way intersection where only traffic going North/South has to stop).

Comment: @Matthew, @Beofett: I have been driving mostly in San Francisco, and there you really have to stop at each intersection. It might be that there are indeed stop signs everywhere though... I might have been looking over that.

Comment: It is worth noting that the "you don't have to stop without a red-light or stop sign" rule is generally subject to the rules of right-of-way (e.g. if there's a car, bike, or pedestrian that has right-of-way over you, you can't plow through them simply because there was no stop sign).

Comment: In Europe (at least the places I know), a stop sign means "stop and yield". Stop signs on all four roads with these rules would bring everything to a stand still. US rules are different.

Answer (score 5):

In the United States, a traffic light showing a green left arrow indicates a "protected left turn": oncoming traffic has a red signal, as do conflicting pedestrian crossings.  Here is an example, taken from an [article](http://pedbikesafe.org/PEDSAFE/countermeasures_detail.cfm?CM_NUM=51) by the Federal Highway Administration:

[image: Left-turn traffic signal, location unknown]

In Europe, a directional arrow signal does not mean that opposing traffic has a red signal.  It just means that you can proceed in the direction indicated by the arrow, but still must yield the right of way as usual.

I was once in Italy, turning left at a 4-way intersection where traffic had to turn left or right because the street directly ahead was a one-way street in the wrong direction.  To indicate this, the signal showed a left green arrow and a right green arrow.  Unfortunately, I irritated an oncoming driver by cutting in front of him.  He also irritated me because I thought he was running a red light.  It was only a few moments later that I realized that I had been in the wrong, and why.

I can imagine that a European driver in the United States, facing a green left arrow, with cars approaching the intersection from the other direction, would probably wait before turning left, at least until it was clear that those cars were stopping.  Any American drivers behind that European would most likely be irritated by that behavior.

Another difference with traffic signals:  Most European signals are designed so it is not possible to see the signal for cross traffic, but this is possible with most American signals.

American intersections typically have at least one signal head on the far side of the intersection.  Among other advantages, this allows the driver stopped at the stop line to see when the signal changes, because the signal is several meters ahead rather than directly overhead.  See, for example, this image:

[image: Intersection of Randall Road and Fabyan Parkway, Geneva, Illinois, United States]

A consequence of this is that when you are waiting at a red light, you can see the signal for the cross traffic at a very oblique angle.  You can usually see which lamp is illuminated by looking for the light reflecting from the sun shades.  When the light for the cross traffic turns yellow, you can prepare to start driving.

European signals are generally placed only at the near side of the intersection.  Some consequences of this difference:

- In Europe, when you stop your car at the stop line, you can't see the main signal head (unless you have a convertible or perhaps a sun roof).  Most signals have a small signal head mounted low on the pole, so the driver of the first car can see when to go.  (If you are stopped at a signal that *lacks* this second, smaller light, and you are tall like me, you have a very difficult time seeing the signal.)  An example:

[image: Red traffic signal in Paris, France]

- If you allow your car to stop a little bit *past* the stop line, you are completely out of luck because you cannot see the signal at all.
- Many European countries have a signal phase immediately preceding the green light, to warn drivers to prepare to start driving.  A couple of seconds before the light turns green, the yellow light turns on, so the signal is showing both red and yellow.  This is not necessary in the US, because drivers can see when the signals are changing.  An example:

[image: Red-and-yellow traffic signal, location unknown]

- In some US intersections, of course, the light doesn't turn green immediately after the cross traffic gets a red light, because, for example, there might be a protected left turn for opposing traffic, or the intersection might be unusually complicated.  In such cases, there is often a sign saying "DELAYED GREEN" or "DELAYED GREEN WAIT" in black letters on a white background.  This is supposed to tell drivers not to start driving when the cross signal turns red, and to wait patiently for their own light to turn green.

[image: Delayed green sign on U.S. traffic signal]

When I was a kid, I had no idea why one might have a "delayed green" -- I always thought, "of course it's delayed; if the green doesn't wait for the other light to turn red, then what's the point of having a traffic light?"

Finally, the delayed green signal can be an arrow indicating a protected left turn.  Here is an example from Harrisonburg, Virginia (see the hburgnews.com [article](http://hburgnews.com/2008/11/25/delayed-green-arrow/) for a discussion):

[image: Left-turn signal in Harrisonburg, Virginia, United States]

(The five-lamp signal has, at the top, a circular red light, with yellow and green arrows on the left, and yellow and green circles on the right.)

Comment: ah the dreaded left turn arrow ... worst invention EVER. it does absolutely nothing for safety and only slows people down. ugh.

Comment: @sgroves I'm confused.  How does it slow people down?

Comment: @sgroves in my research for this question I came across a few instances of left-turn signals that allows left turns even when the turn is unprotected.  An example is the last picture in this answer.  There is also a newer signal that is seen as less ambiguous, showing a flashing yellow left arrow when the left turn is permitted, but unprotected.  Both of these eliminate the problem of being made to wait despite no oncoming traffic.

Comment: you're correct. the problem, of course, is that most left turn signals aren't of the types you described. hopefully in the future they'll be converted, but they continue to be a considerable annoyance across all of the united states. not sure about other countries.

Comment: In the Netherlands at least, the left arrow light _does_ mean that oncoming traffic has red, and if it's different elsewhere in Europe, then that's news to me.

Comment: @phoog In what European country/countries does a left arrow light *not* imply that oncoming traffic has red?

Comment: @gerrit At least in Italy, apparently, judging from the experience I had when I was driving there.

Comment: And in Belgium many intersections have traffic lights "across the street" as in the USA. Not so in The Netherlands. I have driven in around 10 countries (USA, Canada and various European) and mostly it's using common sense. Hah, the good old times when in Belgium they had 3-lane roads. One in each direction and the middle lane... see who's scared first!

Comment: A left arrow before the intersection in Czech Republic means that you have the priority. A left arrow on the opposite side of the intersection (on the left) means that you have the priority AND you should leave the intersection promptly. It may be a bit complicated if you have tram tracks to your left, but general rules apply there.

Answer (score 1):

In California (and possibly in some other states) there is one strange regulation that states that the driveway starts at the curb so be careful when parking. The laws are very strict and it cost me 110 dollars because my car was slightly overlaping with the curb (50cm!). 
[image]

Comment: isn't the SFMTA rule to not park in the red painted zone of the curb?

Comment: Yes, this is an absolute rule. But not all driveways have red curbs and driveway is defined as an areab between the curbs. In EU this is not that strict - nobody cares about the curbs - and as long as you leave enough space for the people to leave everything is fine.

Comment: This also varies greatly between states. In Baltimore, where I grew up, it was not illegal to park in front of a driveway unless specifically restricted by signs, or if painted.

Answer (score -1):

**Corrected**: Great question, but your presumption is *partially* incorrect: the US does have a  <strike>not have a</strike> keep-your-lane system in many states<strike>, except where signs explicitly show</strike>, but not all. <strike>Many drivers do drive that way, but in fact you are supposed to behave in a similar (although not identical) way to how you do in Europe: stay to the right (or left) by default, moving over only to overtake.</strike>.

[This Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_lane#Misuse_and_common_practice) and [this page](http://www.mit.edu/~jfc/right.html) summarise the laws state-by-state.

Comment: This varies state-to-state, and also depending on the number of lanes on the road. http://www.dmv.ca.gov/pubs/hdbk/traffic_lanes.htm#choose_lane specifically states "Do not weave in and out of traffic. Stay in one lane as much as possible". Compared to Australia where there is an explicit "Keep Left Under Overtaking" rule, most of the US is very much a keep-your-lane system - at least on roads with more than 2 lanes.

Comment: Doc, I take it back. On digging deeper, it appears you're right about the "most" qualifier, although some states do still have a left-lane-for-overtaking-only system. This page does a pretty good job of summarising this: http://www.mit.edu/~jfc/right.html. Nevertheless, it is worth pointing out that I've seen "Stay in Lane" signs from time-to-time on highways. I'm now wondering what they are for... if Stay in Lane is the default.

Comment: "Stay in Lane" or "Do Not Pass" signs are normally a short-term instruction, normally at a point where the road ahead would make changing lanes dangerous for some reason. eg, going through a tunnel, roadworks, or sudden lane direction changes.  These signs are normally accompanied by the lines between the lanes changing to solid lines to depict not to change between them.

Comment: The crossing out makes this answer completely unreadable. Don't cross stuff out: just edit to remove the incorrect information. You should be optimizing for the unbounded number of people who might read your answer in the future, not for the few people that might have read it in the 29 minutes between the original and final versions. If those people are curious to know what changed (and they almost certainly aren't), they can look at the edit history.