# Overtaking regulations when driving in Europe

Tags: europe, driving, regulations

I've got a question about how to drive the car in Europe on Highways. In the US, I can overtake another car on either side, and I am fine.

In Europe I was told that I have to drive on the right side (Germany), and to overtake on the left side of the other driver.

Now I had following situation, and I did not know how to handle this properly:
I was driving along on the right lane, the Autobahn was 3 lanes wide on my side, and was going around 110 km/h. Someone overtook me, but he stayed on the middle lane, and suddenly got slower. He wasn't really in front of me, so I could not change to the left lane, but I was told I may not overtake on the right side.

Would I have to brake in such a situation, or should I just ignore it, and overtake him again on the right side?

(I overtook him, and he was on the phone, so I guess that was why he got distracted and slowed down that much).

Comment: Hi Anton, welcome to travel.se. There is a related, if not duplicate question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/711/what-are-the-main-differences-in-traffic-regulations-between-the-us-europe

Comment: I read through that, and it was a general description of what is different, but I have a good idea what is different. In my scenario the other driver behaved contrary to everything I knew he should, so I wondered what I should have done there.

Comment: @AntonRoth One thing to note.  Watch your rear view mirror because people behind you may signal you to move over if they are going much faster then you.  (There is a funny story about a liver driver from the US with regards to that, but it's too long for comments).

Comment: Overtaking on the right is legal in the US?!

Comment: Yes, you can pass on either side. Overtaking a truck on the right is stupid, but legal.

Comment: @gerrit If you've ever driven on a five-lane highway in Europe, you would argue in favor of the "keep your lane" principle. For two or three lane highways, the European system works fine.

Comment: @Bernhard Hmm, I have, but only for a short stretch (maybe 5 km). I probably don't like 5-lane-per-direction highways either way.

Comment: @Anton, note that that is not always the case re: the US; it depends on the state. There is a longer version of that discussion here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9574/2555

Comment: @Bernhard: You are right if there is no "drive as far right as you can" rule, as that might force you to switch several lanes to the left before overtaking. However, the combination of "only overtake on the left" and "drive as far right as you can" makes sense again, as you'll gradually overtake cars that are faster than you while getting faster yourself and switching to the left, one lane at a time. Also on a five+ lane highway.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You are right if everybody would indeed drive as far right as possible. In reality, some people don't do that properly, and your 5-lane highway transforms in a 3-way, with traffic of four lanes having to squeeze through two lanes instead. I've rarely seen it work. On 4-lane highways, I often shift four lanes to the left to overtake someone.

Comment: Europe is big. Different countries have different rules. Please mention specifically what countries are you interested in.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are right about the overtaking rules. You can only overtake on the left side of the other driver. But, there is another rule, you should occupy the right-most lane (except in the UK of course, there it is the other way around).

There are a few exceptions

1. When there is a traffic jam ahead, and traffic is going slower, you can (and should) overtake on the right side.
2. On a multiple lane road with exits on the left, you may overtake a driver on the right, if he signalling to turn left.

In the specific situation you are referring to, it does depend on what is happening in front of you. In case of normal traffic, you were not allowed to overtake him, even though he was braking. Maybe the speed limit changed at that location, and was that the reason for braking?

Overtaking on the right is especially dangerous, as drivers in Europe do not expect this. Even tough someone is not obeying the 'keep right' rule (and is phoning). So, what you should have done, officially, is brake, change two lanes to the left, then overtake, and change two lanes back again. In practice, most Europeans would do what you did, and give the other driver the angry face (if he really had no reason to brake).

Comment: I swear, the Autobahn was pretty much empty, and there was no speed limit. So thanks for the confirmation, I was like, thats a stupid situation...

Comment: Mostly right, but be aware that both the exact regulations (e.g. when you are allowed to overtake on the right side) and the driving culture (how these regulations are lived up to in practice) are very different between European countries.

Comment: As far as I know, overtaking on right is not infraction if it's road with divided carriageways or one way carriageway; or the carriageway has at least three lanes in your direction. Also I do agree that it's not the safest way, but I wouldn't say that it's uncommon.

Comment: @vartec it depends on the country.

Comment: "I swear, the Autobahn was pretty much empty, and there was no speed limit." Note that it's quite hard to recognise speed limit changes on the autobahn; it's a well-known problem for folks new to the autobahn.  But yeah, just "don't pass on the right" it's that simple.

Comment: The more extreme variants or such cases raise interesting questions. What if someone is driving in a lane left to you, a few meters in front of you, and slams hard on the brakes? Must you also slam hard on the brakes, potentially creating a safety hazard, or at least blocking traffic at best, to avoid accidentally overtaking? What if the one left to you almost stops? Must you also stop and clog the traffic (as you can no longer overtake on the left without reversing or waiting for a long time)?

Comment: @vsz That is why there is an exception for traffic jams.

Comment: @Bernhard : none of my two examples must necessarily be traffic jams. They could in theory happen with only two cars on the whole highway.

Comment: Well, the driver of the braking car is bringing other drivers in danger. They will not fine you for overtaking, but the other driver.

Answer (score 13):

If you were in **Romania**, you **wouldn't** have broken any laws. 
The Romanian law makes a clear difference between **overtaking** and **passing**.

In Romania, you can overtake on the **left lane only**, but you can **pass on all lanes**.

**Overtaking** (is the same as in US and all the countries of the EU): signal left, change lane, move in front.

**Passing** (as being described by the Romanian legislation): you cruise on the motorway and you encounter a vehicle on your left or right lane moving slower than you and you simply keep your lane and pass him.

The difference between passing and overtaking is that when you overtake you move from one lane to another and the distance to the vehicle in front of you is smaller than 100m. When you change lanes and the distance between cars is bigger than 100m you legally execute the change lane maneuver. After you execute a change lane maneuver, you encounter a vehicle moving slower than you on your left or right lane and you cruise along him, you would be executing the passing maneuver, NOT overtaking.

Long story short, if the situation you described would have happened in Romania, you would have legally passed him on the right lane.

I have discovered that most of EU countries do not make the difference between overtaking and passing.

I added this as an answer because it was too long for a comment.

Comment: @motoDrizzt: Certainly not in Germany.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you got it backwards. "Overtaking" happens  when you get ahead of another vehicle without changing lanes. "Passing" happens when you actively change lanes to get ahead of another vehicle.

Answer (score 3):

In Poland overtaking on the left is legal on motorways and any other roads with lanes in both directions separated. It is also legal on roads with three lanes in each direction outside cities and two lanes within city limit.

E.g. (page in polish, but has pictures) http://www.strefakulturalnejjazdy.pl/2013/06/czy-mozna-wyprzedzac-z-prawej-strony.html

Comment: I think you mean _overtaking on the *right*_.