# In countries with a "Keep right/left unless overtaking" rule: May I keep the left/right lane if driving at speed limit?

Tags: usa, europe, legal, safety, driving

As far as I have read, overtaking over speed limit is *always* illegal. So do I need to keep in left if I am at speed limit and no one can overtake me legally? It is also less tedious to just stick to one lane and cruise at a legal top speed rather than go to left lane, overtake, switch back to right lane N number of times.

This is of course keeping in mind that emergency vehicles are always given passage.

Comment: It's "keep *right* unless overtaking" in the right-hand-drive countries of the US and mainland Europe.

Comment: I edited the title to avoid closing the question as "too broad". Now it is specifically addressing the countries where this law applies and should be a valid question.

Comment: It's still going to depend on the jurisdiction, as you can see from the long list of answers of the form *well, where I live…* As such, the question is still too broad.

Comment: Please don't do this ... ever.  Blocking the left lane when not using it to overtake will in fact get you fined in many countries (including Canada).

Comment: In the UK (drives on the left) you should use the left hand lane except when overtaking. Failing to do so is an offence, counting as driving without due care and attention. Most would regard this as a more serious offence than speeding.

Comment: Please note, in some countries with these laws in place the speed limits do not apply to (non electric) bicycles so technically someone can still legally overtake you.

Comment: Plus - how do you know you are going at the speed-limit? Your speedometer may be mildly inaccurate, and your speed may drift down occasionally - putting you completely in the wrong. Or the other driver may have an inaccurate speedo and believe you are obstructing, leading to conflict.

Comment: Also, you are not the traffic police, you have no authority to enforce traffic speed limits. There are emergency examples of when someone may need to exceed the limit, and you are not to know so do not block traffic

Answer (score 22):

In mainland Europe the rule is actually *occupy the free rightmost lane* unless when overtaking. In other words, the leftmost lane should be used exclusively for overtaking and not to cruise in. Indeed doing so is an offence and could result in a fine regardless of whether you are driving at the speed limit and nobody can legally overtake you.

It follows that one should never undertake (overtake on the right) ([although some countries do allow "passing" on the right](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13783/overtaking-regulations-when-driving-in-europe)). [The Wikipedia page on overtaking is very informative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtaking) on the subject, and has a list of rules regarding undertaking by country.

Comment: In Italy, **if there are three lanes**, you are in the rightmost, and you want to overtake someone that is (wrongly) in the middle one, then it it allowed to overtake him on the right. This is since it is (rightly) considered safer to just pass him on the right, rather than move two lanes to your left, overtake, and move again two lanes to your right (while cursing the idiot).

Comment: @Lohoris To my knowledge undertaking is considered a traffic offence in Italy.

Comment: Except in this very specific case, as far as I know. I've learned this quite recently, but unfortunately I don't remember the source.

Comment: @o0'. What's the difference between the specific case you described and the definition of "undertaking"?

Answer (score 15):

In general, **no**.
Germany e.g. changed the law from the necessity to drive right at all times to allow staying in a lane *if and only if* there are vehicles on the right side for approximately every 20 seconds.

If the road is empty, you are *obliged* to drive right. No exceptions.

It depends on culture, but e.g. in Germany it is not your business to dictate other people how to drive. The most important law here is the first law:

> Wer am Verkehr teilnimmt hat sich so zu verhalten, dass kein Anderer geschädigt, gefährdet oder mehr, als nach den Umständen unvermeidbar, behindert oder belästigt wird. (People who are road users have to act in a way that no other people are harmed or endangered. They also should not encumber or pester other people if this is not strictly necessary.)

And yes, driving left without reason other than being comfortable is considered encumbering.

Comment: All the rationalisations for the aggressive driving going on there are not entirely convincing, Germans do make it their business to force you to switch lanes to make room for them. It's not like they would refrain from pestering you or slow down in advance in the name of safety.

Comment: Forcing people to slow down by needlessly occupying the fast lane is considered aggressive in Germany and many other countries. It is also strictly illegal in many places. On top of that, it can create dangerous situations - as a driver your first thought shouldn't be what your rights are, but what you can do to make traffic as safe as possible.

Comment: Uh, that's not a rationalization, it is interpretation of law: *Oberlandesgericht Düsseldorf Az.: 2b Ss 1/00 - 10/00*.  While in this case the driver was discharged because the former jury was not attentive enough, it was laid out that deliberate continous driving on the left *is not acceptable*. That in our culture aggressive driving is so predominant and accepted is something I cannot explain, bill it as a negative quirk of Germany.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I know all that but that's not really the point. It's all about nuances also. I don't like people needlessly keeping left either but that's not a reason to drive close to them, make light signals or expect someone to switch to the middle lane when doing so would force them to slow down sharply to fit in the flow. That's just as dangerous and that's happening daily. So the notion that it's all about driving rationally, following the rules and safety simply isn't plausible.

Comment: @Relaxed It is not permitted to overtake on the right lane. So it is not about "needlessly keeping left", *driving on the left lane is actively blocking people from overtaking forcing everyone to drive with the speed of the left lane vehicle*. So it is allowed to make *one* light signal (not driving close or a light show) to inform the driver that someone wants to overtake him. It is also easy to avoid: Look left before you overtake, let fast cars pass and wait until the left lane is free. Granted, I am using a motorcycle and I don't want to end as radiator deco, but it works for a car, too.

Comment: @ThorstenS. It's precisely because overtaking on the right is not permitted that someone needlessly keeping left would annoy someone driving faster !? But like I said, it's not easy to avoid and I am certainly not talking about jumping out in front of somebody else, you can be driving plenty fast and overtaking several cars in a row, you will still find people who weren't even visible when you started your manoeuvre and still think you should go back to the right lane immediately and stand up on the brakes so that they can get a little faster.

Comment: Also, whatever is or isn't “allowed” or ought to happen, driving as close as many people do on German motorways is objectively dangerous, no matter what. That's the point where the whole theory that it is about “safety” loses all credibility. Maybe someone else previously did something mildly dangerous or technically illegal but it that's the new situation you now have to deal with. If you get close because you're annoyed or they *should* have behaved differently, you have no business lecturing them about safety.

Comment: @Relaxed Exactly, you did understand it :-D Remember, it has a reason that Germany is still one the countries with limitless *autobahns* and has an automobile club with 20 million members, which is one fourth of the German population. We are taking car driving very seriously. You can criticize that as much as you want and your criticism may have merit, we won't change anyway.

Comment: "Forcing people to slow down by needlessly occupying the fast lane is considered aggressive in Germany and many other countries. " - yes, but riding up on someone's rear bumper to show your displeasure at the fact that they're not going fast enough in the fast lane is _also_ aggressive, so if people in Germany are willing to do that it means they have no particular cultural opposition to aggressive driving in general, so "it is not your business to dictate other people how to drive" is clearly false. They try to dictate how I drive, I try to dictate how they drive, it's fun for everyone.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Well, I understand that, but I would hope, you, at least, could present it with a bit more distance ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenS. Have you actually read and in any way at least halfways understood the verdict you are linking to? The driver was not acquitted or discharged, there is no such thing as a jury in the German judicial system and the court ascertained that driving in the left lane without obvious reason for several km is not necessarily a violation of German law.

Answer (score 6):

1. If you are going "the speed-limit", in almost every location I've ever lived in the US, you are the slowest person on the road.
2. If you are the slowest person you aren't passing.
3. If you aren't passing and you are on the left, then you are breaking the law (where applicable).
4. If you are going above the speed limit, and other cars are stuck behind you then, sooner or later, you are going to make people pass on your right.

Whether you are "right" for actually following the speed limit or not is rendered moot by the fact that by not passing you are no longer following another law: Slow traffic to the right.

I can drive 10 over the speed limit in most places and constantly get passed. In many places in California, going 10 over on the highway would be the slowest lane. Going 10 over in the fast lane would be asking for a road rage indecent.

Comment: So speed limit is just a "suggestion" ? Or everyone travel over speed limit betting there wont be a speed trap in the road? Or ppl think paying the speed ticket is worth the extra 20 over the limit?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've noticed that on highways in the US, everyone drives at least 20 over. Which is not to say that rules are a suggestion, just that people do that

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, unless enforced, a speed limit is a suggestion. Where you have five-digit fines (Switzerland), a speed camera every mile or so (Oman), long section control stretches (Austria), high density of mobile control (The Netherlands) and/or can be jailed even for moderate speeding (Italy, some U.S. states), the speed limit may be more than just that.

Comment: It's not "just a suggestion", it's simply "safety in numbers". If everyone drives like that then cops can't halt everyone doing 10 over limit, because they would have to halt literally **everyone**. Speed traps are also set to some value over the limit, otherwise they too would flood local authorities with unending stream of photos.

Comment: As @Alexander say depend on how enforced is. In my country I know is just a suggestion because not exists speed trap. But say you should drive over the limit on US just because other drivers are is irresponsable. My brother almost get a speed ticket in a vacation for following a faster car (not close) thinking that was the right speed. The front car got the ticket and he slow down for the rest of holiday.

Comment: In some places the police themselves are driving 10-20 over the limit because that's the speed that traffic flows safely at.  The limits should be increased in those places but its far too expensive and requires a lot of effort to get higher limits instated.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's a combination of "suggestion", "protection of the herd", is it worth the cops time to pull you over (Google "9 your fine, 10 your mine".) - In many places the cop will pull you over at 15+ over - to account for fudge factor in recording equipment - so that you got clocked doing 15+ but you get a ticket for 10+, route you take (Some places rely more on ticket income than others), etc. The only time I've gotten tickets, personally, have been 15+ - mainly when speed drops going through a town and I'm not paying attention.

Comment: @Agent_L: LEOs can and do ticket some offenders if they can't ticket everyone. There is no law that says traffic officers have to be "fair" when handing out citations.

Answer (score 4):

Here in Ireland you will receive a fine and licence points, if you drive in the overtaking lanes but are not overtaking, regardless of your speed.

Overtaking lane is any lane, other than the left most lane.

*edit* That is the law, implementation of this is almost non existent

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have already pointed out, the laws vary greatly from one country to another.

Here in Spain you would be fined and I think that you will also lose points in your driver license.

I would like to point out that here **overtaking over the speed limit** is not illegal. In fact, you can go faster than the speed limit when overtaking (by 20 km/h) in some specified situations, so, even if you drive at the speed limit, you could be always legally overtaken.

Comment: Whether exceeding the speed limit to overtake is legal or not varies with country. In the US it isn't legal, though it's common.