# What are the differences between French road signs and American road signs?

Tags: usa, france, driving, automobiles

I'm looking for a comparison between French road signs and American road signs, just like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_European_road_signs) regarding European road signs.

The more exhaustive comparison, the better, but I'm mostly interested in the most common road signs that are different between the USA and France (so that this question is not too broad for Stack Exchange).

Comment: I guess the American road signs will *tell* you what to do. For ex, I have never seen different 'Give Way ahead' - 100/200/400 mts sign in the US. Its just a Yield sign. Its assumed to be common sense to know that the other vehicle has the right of way.  A stop sign means, well, stop.

Comment: As a French, American road signs do not tell always tell me what to do. E.g. if you do a right turn on red in France, you're in *big* trouble.

Comment: @happybuddha not sure what you mean there - both 'Yield' and 'Give Way' seem to me to "tell you what to do", no?

Comment: A *give way ahead* sign is quite important if you're approaching an intersection at 80 km/hour in a rural area.

Comment: When someone finds a sign that says "Give way" in the US let me know.  This would become a tourist attraction. :-)

Comment: @Karlson Why would it?

Comment: @gerrit Because US uses Yield instead.  You will find Give Way in members of the British Commonwealth.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you have example I'd like to see.  The example you use is not really a sign problem but a rules knowledge problem.  In Europe there is no indication that right on red is not allowed.  Nor there is an indication what [this sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vorschriftszeichen_13a.svg) means. In Quebec and elsewhere there is no indication on signs what a flashing green mean and so on, which normally means that you take an explanation of road rules from the car rental company before getting on the road.

Comment: @AakashM Excellent Question ! Did you look at the (Give Way) signs OP posted ? Do you know what a Yield sign in the US looks like ? Once you compare the both, you will see what the Yield sign in the US will not 'tell' you to do. It wont 'tell' you to Yield in 2/4/800 mtrs. You just yield.

Comment: @Karlson Turning right on red exists in Europe too... [example one](http://www.gratisrijbewijsonline.be/voorrangwet/afbeeldingen/voorrangwet14.JPG), [example two](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gr%C3%BCner_Pfeil.jpg).

Comment: @gerrit I fail to see your point.  Green light arrow means green light in that direction.  I can take a picture of an intersection with no green arrow and it still won't have the sign saying "No Right Turn on Red".  Also there is no explanation of what example 2 actually means.  Based on snow routes in US I can safely assume "Green Route" that way.

Comment: @Karlson Those examples show both the red light *and* the green arrow.  That may be confusing to someone unfamiliar with the situation.  But of course the traffic regulations are not repeated on every intersection.

Comment: @gerrit Green light isn't really confusing, whether with Red main light or without it.  My point was that you need to know at least basic rules of the road instead of having signs everywhere to tell you what they are.

Comment: @happybuddha I've image-googled 'yield sign usa' and I've found pictures of downward-pointing red hollow triangles, remarkably similar to Euro 'Give Way' signs. Are these not **signs telling you to yield**? They certainly look like that to me.

Comment: @AakashM The American Yield sign will have the words Yield *written* with the sign. That's how its *telling* me to yield. Also I am not aware if anywhere in the USA the yield sign will tell the distance while yielding. Like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Belgian_road_sign_B3.svg

Comment: @happybuddha [yield ahead](http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2099/2268766601_b610f337f9_m.jpg).

Comment: @gerrit Must have been an excellent driver to meet with that sign.

Comment: Related (more general): [What are the main differences in traffic regulations between the US/Europe?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/711/what-are-the-main-differences-in-traffic-regulations-between-the-us-europe)

Comment: @Gilles Awesome, thanks! Also, I like your answer, good to know :)

Comment: There's a difference between France and other European countries that doesn't appear on the Wikipedia page. In France, a sign on the left-hand side of the road pointing right means "go straight on", almost everywhere else it means "turn right". Many visitors have been caught out by that one!

Comment: France follows Vienna Convention on Road Signs and Signals whereas the US follows MUTCD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

About the closest way that I'm aware of is the category for this on Wikipedia.  Of course, it'll still require you to click through each one.

[Category: Diagrams of road signs in France](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDiagrams_of_road_signs_of_France)

[Category: Diagrams of road signs in the United States](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDiagrams_of_road_signs_of_the_United_States)

That European comparison is amazing, and I'm hoping another answer appears with something similar, but this is the best I can locate.

Note: even on a state-by-state basis, in the US, [there are custom state road signs as well](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDiagrams_of_road_signs_of_the_United_States_by_state).

Comment: Almost all the "custom state road signs" are simply state and county highway markers and tourism board signs. The basic color, type, and shape schemata are otherwise consistent nationally.

Comment: Just FYI.  The US Road Signage is defined and controlled by the [Federal Highway Administration](http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/) making them uniform across the US.

Comment: All on one page: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Road_signs_of_the_United_States